# How do I customize the Stack Exchange dropdown menu?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

I swear that a few weeks ago, there was an option to customize which communities were displayed in the dropdown. I no longer see this option. A search of the site and FAQs gave unhelpful results.

Comment: It is still in the drop down menu for me at the left in the top bar

Comment: Well, yes, there it is. Please ignore my idiocy.

Comment: Sure, from now on or just for this post?

Comment: It's also in the new nav bar (hamburger at the right hand end) for SO users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Comment: That's a very abstract circle... ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Ceci n'est pas une spirale….

Comment: @NathanTuggy hmm? Why French?!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: [The Treason of Images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images).